# Can I style my current geographical position in google maps api V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps api v3. In my map the current position name is showing larger than other names, but it is not easy to me to find it in the fist time, so I thought to style my current position, like, bold the text, change the color of the text, I searched but no answer.

This is my code:

```
  function initialize() {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(geoip_latitude(),geoip_longitude());
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: true,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
      },
      zoomControl: true,
      zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
      }

    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);

  }
```

Can I add a option to `var myOptions = {` to style my current location. In this case my current location is `colombo.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best you can do within the confines of the API is to place something (such as a `Marker` object) on your current location.  I don't believe the API permits you to style some labels and not others (and if it does, then it is probably not a way that is documented and straightforward).